# How to POST binary files with AngularJS (with upload DEMO)

Tags: angularjs, angular-http, angularjs-fileupload

### unable to send file with angular post call

I am trying to post `.mp4` file with some data through ionic 1 with angular 1. While posting through POSTMAN it is fine and working. I am getting `Success = false` in my application.

**in POSTMAN**, no headers and data is bellow,
Service url with POST request http://services.example.com/upload.php
body in form data

```
j_id = 4124, type = text   
q_id = 6, type = text   
u_id = 159931, type = text 
file = demo.mp4, type = file
```

**in my app:**

```
$rootScope.uploadQuestion = function () {

    var form = new FormData();
    form.append("j_id", "4124");
    form.append("q_id", "6");
    form.append("u_id", "159931");
    form.append("file", $rootScope.videoAns.name); //this returns media object which contain all details of recorded video

    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data' }, // also tried with application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        url: 'http://services.example.com/upload.php',
        // url: 'http://services.example.com/upload.php?j_id=4124&q_id=8&u_id=159931&file='+$rootScope.videoAns.fullPath,
        // data: "j_id=" + encodeURIComponent(4124) + "&q_id=" + encodeURIComponent(8) + "&u_id=" + encodeURIComponent(159931) +"&file=" + encodeURIComponent($rootScope.videoAns), 
        data: form,
        cache: false,
        timeout: 300000
    }).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
        if (status == '200') {
            if (data.success == "true") {
                alert('uploading...');
            }


        }


    }).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {

    });
}
```

Comment: Avoid putting functions on `$rootScope`. Instead, encapsulate functions in AngularJS services. It makes the code easier to test and maintain. For more information, see [AngularJS FAQ - `$rootScope` exists, but it can be used for evil](https://docs.angularjs.org/misc/faq#-rootscope-exists-but-it-can-be-used-for-evil).

Comment: The `.success` and `.error` methods are deprecated. For more information, see [Why are angular $http success/error methods deprecated? Removed from v1.6?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35329384/why-are-angular-http-success-error-methods-deprecated-removed-from-v1-6/35331339#35331339).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## **RECOMMENDED:** POST Binary Files Directly

Posting binary files with `multi-part/form-data` is inefficient as the [base64 encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64) adds an extra 33% overhead. If the server API accepts POSTs with binary data, post the file directly:

```
function upload(url, file) {
    if (file.constructor.name != "File") {
       throw new Error("Not a file");
    }
    var config = {
        headers: {'Content-Type': undefined},
        transformRequest: []
    };
    return $http.post(url, file, config)
      .then(function (response) {
        console.log("success!");
        return response;
    }).catch(function (errorResponse) {
        console.error("error!");
        throw errorResponse;
    });
}
```

Normally the [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) encodes JavaScript objects as [JSON strings](http://www.json.org/). Use `transformRequest: []` to override the default transformation.

---

## [DEMO of Direct POST](https://plnkr.co/edit/B3yMoGciAGcdicOaHlUZ?p=preview)

```js
angular.module("app",[])
.directive("selectNgFiles", function() {
  return {
    require: "ngModel",
    link: postLink
  };
  function postLink(scope, elem, attrs, ngModel) {
    elem.on("change", function(event) {
      ngModel.$setViewValue(elem[0].files);
    });
  }
})
.controller("ctrl", function($scope, $http) {
  var url = "//httpbin.org/post";
  var config = {
    headers: { 'Content-type': undefined }
  };
  $scope.upload = function(files) {
    var promise = $http.post(url,files[0],config);
    promise.then(function(response){
      $scope.result="Success "+response.status;
    }).catch(function(errorResponse) {
      $scope.result="Error "+errorRespone.status;
    });
  };
})
```

```html
<script src="//unpkg.com/angular/angular.js"></script>
  <body ng-app="app" ng-controller="ctrl">
    <input type="file" select-ng-files ng-model="files">
    <br>
    <button ng-disabled="!files" ng-click="upload(files)">
      Upload file
    </button>
    <pre>
    Name={{files[0].name}}
    Type={{files[0].type}}
    RESULT={{result}}
    </pre>
  </body>
```

---

## Posting with `'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'`

When posting data using the [FormData API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), it is important to set the content type to `undefined`:

```
function uploadQuestion(file) {

    var form = new FormData();
    form.append("j_id", "4124");
    form.append("q_id", "6");
    form.append("u_id", "159931");
    form.append("file", file); //this returns media object which contain all details of recorded video

    return $http({
        method: 'POST',
        headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined ̶'̶m̶u̶l̶t̶i̶p̶a̶r̶t̶/̶f̶o̶r̶m̶-̶d̶a̶t̶a̶'̶ }, // also tried with application/x-www-form-urlencoded
        url: 'http://services.example.com/upload.php',
        data: form,
        ̶c̶a̶c̶h̶e̶:̶ ̶f̶a̶l̶s̶e̶,̶ 
        timeout: 300000
    ̶}̶)̶.̶s̶u̶c̶c̶e̶s̶s̶(̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶(̶d̶a̶t̶a̶,̶ ̶s̶t̶a̶t̶u̶s̶,̶ ̶h̶e̶a̶d̶e̶r̶s̶,̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶f̶i̶g̶)̶ ̶{̶
    }).then(function(response) {
        var data = response.data;
        var status = response.status;
        if (status == '200') {
           console.log("Success");
        }    
    ̶}̶)̶.̶e̶r̶r̶o̶r̶(̶f̶u̶n̶c̶t̶i̶o̶n̶ ̶(̶d̶a̶t̶a̶,̶ ̶s̶t̶a̶t̶u̶s̶,̶ ̶h̶e̶a̶d̶e̶r̶s̶,̶ ̶c̶o̶n̶f̶i̶g̶)̶ ̶{̶
    }).catch(function(response) {
        console.log("ERROR");
        //IMPORTANT
        throw response;    
    });
}
```

When the [XHR API send method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send) sends a [FormData Object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData), it automatically sets the content type header with the appropriate boundary. When the [$http service](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http) overrides the content type, the server will get a content type header without the proper boundary.

Comment: I get the response in success, but I am still unable to post file at location. I am getting `app/video/video` in response however I should get this response `app/video/video.mp4`

Comment: I have already used content-type as undefined and I was getting above response as now

Comment: @Mangrio The code in the answer is correct as written. Your problems come from either the server code or the code that obtains the `file` object, neither of which are included in the question.

Comment: how to get file progress % ?