# how i can upload file using custom keys

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have to create a quiz system for the website. I have to  upload image type question and also image type options on single page using angularjs and webapi. I want to check in api that which image is for option and which image is for question image while array of image is with name visible I can show images in array here is my code:

```
app.directive('uploadFiles', function () {
return {
    scope: true,        //create a new scope  
    link: function (scope, el, attrs) {
        el.bind('change', function (event) {
            var files = event.target.files;
            console.info(files);
            for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                scope.$emit("seletedFile", { file: files[i] });
            }
        });
    }
};
});
```

```
app.controller('questionairController', function ($scope, $http) {
    $scope.files = [];

    $scope.$on("seletedFile", function (event, args) {
        $scope.fileList = true;
        $scope.$apply(function () {
            $scope.files.push(args.file);
        });
    });

    $scope.addQuestionair = function () {
        var cID = document.getElementById("CustomerID").value;
        var pID = document.getElementById("ProjectID").value;

        $scope.question.CustomerID = cID;
        $scope.question.ProjectID = pID;

        console.info($scope.question);
        console.info($scope.OptionsList);

        var viewObj = {
            questionair: $scope.question,
            options: $scope.OptionsList
        };

        console.info(viewObj);
```

```
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            url: 'api/Questions/AddQuestion',
            headers: { 'Content-Type': undefined },
            uploadEventHandlers: {
                progress: function (e) {
                    if (e.lengthComputable) {
                        var progressValue = (e.loaded / e.total) * 100;
                        $scope.ProgressWidth = 0;
                        $scope.ProgressWidth = { 'width': progressValue + '%' };
                    }
                }
            },
            transformRequest: function (data) {
                console.info("in transform");
                var formData = new FormData();
                formData.append("model", angular.toJson(data.model));
                for (var i = 0; i < data.files.length; i++) {
                    formData.append(data.files[i].name, data.files[i]);
                }
                return formData;
            },
            data: { model: viewObj, files: $scope.files }
        }).then(function (response) {
            console.info(response);
            $scope.SaveMessage = response.data;
            GetQuestionair();
            $scope.question = null;
        }, function (error) {

        });
    };
```

Here is my API function

```
    [HttpPost]
    public HttpResponseMessage AddQuestion()
    {
        if (!Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.UnsupportedMediaType);
        }

        HttpFileCollection hfc = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files;
        var model = HttpContext.Current.Request["model"];

        ViewModel viewModel = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ViewModel>(model);
        if (viewModel == null)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }

        var root = HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/SiteImages/");

        if (!Directory.Exists(root))
        {
            Directory.CreateDirectory(root);
        }

        HttpPostedFile hpf = hfc[0];

        if (hpf.ContentLength > 0)
        { 
            hpf.SaveAs(root + "/" + Path.GetFileName(hpf.FileName));
        }
        {
            db.Tbl_Questionair.Add(viewModel.questionair);
            db.SaveChanges();

            foreach (var item in viewModel.options)
            {
                item.CreatedOn = DateTime.Now;
                item.QID = viewModel.questionair.ID;
                item.CustomerID = viewModel.questionair.CustomerID;
                item.ProjectID = viewModel.questionair.ProjectID;
                db.Options.Add(item);
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Data successfully saved!");
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why does the code use a `for` loop to `$emit` an event for each file? Why not emit only one event and send the entire array?

Comment: Why does the code for the $http call have an error handler that converts rejected promises to fulfilled promises? Do you want it to ignore errors?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [File Upload using AngularJS](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45600736/5535245) or [How to POST binary files with AngularJS (with upload DEMO)](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45433364/5535245)